# Why doesn't skipeWhile display the correct results?

Tags: rxjs

`SkipWhile()` continues to skip elements as long as the entry condition is true. When the condition becomes false, all remaining elements will return.

**What I'm trying to do are two types of conditions:**

1. It must enter when `loading === false` and when `arrIds.length > 0`
2. It must enter when `loading === false` and when `arrIds.length === 0`

My Example:

```
combineLatest([this.peopleSelectorsService.loading, this.peopleSelectorsService.allIds])
    .pipe(skipWhile((observables) => !observables[0] && observables[1].length === 0))
    .subscribe((observables) => {

    });
```

RESULT:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first emission is `[true, []]`

your skip condition can be rewritten as:

```
skipWhile(([loading, items]) => !loading && !items.length)
```

in english: `skip while not loading and there are not items`, in your first emission case this evaluates to `false && true` which is `false`.

`skipWhile` stops skipping after one `false` result, so the first emission stops it from evaluating anymore.

you either need to adjust your logic or use a different operator. can't say for sure as you haven't outlined your expected results. what I SUSPECT you want is:

```
skipWhile(([loading, items]) => loading || !items.length)
```

which will skip the first 2 emissions and emit the third.

Comment: The problem is that with this functionality what is being compared needs to be exactly the same, for example:

In my example I do not know exactly how much data is in my database so it does not enter the condition correctly, but if I compare it with the exact same number it does.